# Tengo un problema con una variable en api wordpress flutter

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter

estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio en flutter, para obtener los posts de wordpress. Pero me sale este error en la variable del total de los posts itemCount: snapshot.data.length
Si alguien me puede ayudar... porque si hago lo que dice el corrector de visual studio no arreglo nada!!!
GRACIAS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay que compartir el código como imagen. Lee [porque no](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976) y [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Puedes probar a poner snapshot.data?.lenght ?? 0, para asegurarte de que si ese parámetro no viene, no se pinte nada y no pete la aplicación.

Comment: el mismo editor de código te esta mencionando que el operador "!" es para que no vengan datos vacíos en alguna de tus variables, también si es haciendo una List.view, tendrás parte de la función que consume tu api de wordprees?? la otra cosa que también debes olvidar en un ListView.builder es añadir ,desde que posición vas a mostrar los elementos ejemplo => `snapshot.data.length[index]`